# Pdf export not work in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, export, kendo-grid

I am developing a application in which data is display in kendo grid.Now I want to export this pdf/excel.
For this I create a sample - 
http://jsfiddle.net/pporwal26/y6KdK/83/

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["pdf"],
    pdf: {
        allPages: true
    },
    pageable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 2,
        refresh: true,
        change: function(e) {
            nextData(e.index);
        }
    },
    dataSource: {
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: {
            data: "FileList",
            total: "total",
        },
        data: jsonData
    },

});
}
```

In this sample I have two problems -

1. export this grid in pdf/excel.
2. When I click on next page my next page json is come from the function.Si I want that I download pdf with all page data.

Comment: Have you looked at Kendo's documentation to [Export to PDF](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export)

Comment: Yes..I read this.But I cant understand what is problem with my code..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have referenced JZIP script. You can use this CDN:

```
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"
```